# Git from local to FTP (not working copy)

Tags: php, git, deployment, ssh

What's the best way to push (publish) my local repository to both bitbucket and my shared host (hostgator)?

I'm using Windows with Git.

Actually, i can `git push` to bitbucket and works. But I would like to publish in my FTP (shared host), but I think great to publish only the files, not the `.git` folder, in other words, the working copy (clone).

Actually i access the ssh via git bash, and hit `git clone ...` but this is'not a good/better way (I think).

So I saw this link: `http://github.com/resmo/git-ftp` and also `http://github.com/ezyang/git-ftp`
but i would like to know if exists better way to do this without have to install python or other softwaer like cygwin.

My projects are little (about 3mb), so isn't necessary to send only the changed files. can be all the files.

I have looked at many links about this, and I tried other ways, but maybe there are a good and simple way to do this... because this I came to stackoverflow to ask for your all help.

Answer (score 0):

You have several different options:

1)  Create a script locally which does a git push to bitbucket, a `git checkout-index -a -f --prefix=/destination/path/` to a local directory and then ftp's that local directory up to your ftp server.

2)  Create a new remote which points to a bare repository on the ftp server, and then create a post-receive hook which does the `git checkout-index -a -f --prefix=/destination/path/` on the ftp server.  Once this is setup you'd do a `git push` and `git push ftp` (which could be aliased to one command if desired)

3)  Use git archive to point to a remote repository:  `git archive --format=tar --remote=ssh://remote_server/remote_repository master | (cd /path/to/dir/ && tar -xf -)`  Obviously, you'd want to create an alias for this command.

Comment: I already tried something like your second item: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-perfect-workflow-with-git-github-and-ssh/ but don't worked... I don't know why, maybe cause in this tutorial he was using Github intead Bitbucket. But doesn't worked.

Comment: Looks like that could work.  However, I'm not familiar with the workings of bitbucket, so I can't advise you there.  However, if you separate the push to bitbucket and the push to your ftp site, pushing to the ftp site will have nothing to do with bitbucket.  You can still combine both pushes into one alias so it's a single command.  You'll just be pushing to two sites with one command rather than the ftp push going through bitbucket.

Comment: I'm trying the second option. Where I must place this code: `git checkout-index -a -f --prefix=/destination/path/`? At a PHP file? and then upload to the POST service at bitbucket? This code will work in PHP file? @wadesworld

Comment: No, as I said, it goes in a post-receive hook in your git repository on the ftp site.  See [Git Hook Explanation] (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)